# Web Application is responding very slow at the time of JMeter Load Test

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

At the time of JMeter load testing on a web application, App is responding very very slow.

What are the parameters should we check and how we will do monitoring at the time of load testing, Give me valuable suggestions?

Comment: For monitoring your app's behaviour while running JMeter Test you should use "Perfmon Metrics Collector".It is a JMeter plugin available in [Standard Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/).Using it, you can monitor [CPU, Memory, Swap, Disks I/O and Networks I/O](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonMetrics/) on almost all platforms!

Answer (score 1):

The next step is to find out *what* is slowing down. What kind of monitoring do you have in place? Do the requests go through an app server and query a database? Either of those could be the bottleneck. But on each of those servers, it could be CPU, Memory, thread pools, Network ports, or any number of things.

Once you have monitoring in place, you can figure out what's going wrong. At that point you fix that, then run again and find your next bottleneck.

I can't point out exactly what that bottleneck will be- you're the expert on your own application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449575/need-an-urgent-help-regarding-jmeter
Kindly please review the above URL for complete detail and give me your valuable suggestion.

Comment: As both I and @halfer have stated- this isn't a JMeter problem. JMeter will put enough pressure on a system that it will crack- but it won't tell you 1) where it cracked or 2) how to fix it. You need (1) to get (2) and you need monitoring to get (2).